# What is the meaning of pin/unpin a repository in github?

Tags: github

What is the meaning of pin/unpin a repository in github? what will happen to a repository if I pin/unpin it? I'm quite curious about it.

Comment: Pinning is described pretty well here: http://www.ericsink.com/Beyond_CheckOut_and_CheckIn.html

Comment: Thanks Robert, this page has helped me a lot:)

Answer (score 5):

In June 2016, pinning a repository acquire a new feature:
See "[Pin repositories to your GitHub profile](https://github.com/blog/2191-pin-repositories-to-your-github-profile)"

> **You can now showcase the repositories that best represent your work on your GitHub profile**.
>   Using the "Pinned repositories" list, you can pin any public repository you have contributed to. Once you have chosen up to five repositories, you can then drag-and-drop to place them in whatever order you like.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/82317/16124539/f608ebb8-33b4-11e6-9df8-6bc3182696a7.gif]

> If you don't customize your pinned repositories, we'll continue to show your most popular repositories.